# Calculating average miles walked per day with while loop

Tags: c

I am unable to get the input to be added and get the correct output for the average.

The code below is as far as I have made it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  /* variable definition: */
   int days;
   float avg, miles;
/* Initialize */
   days=1;
// Loop through to input values

while(days<=7) {
      printf("Enter the number of miles for each day walked.");
      // use %lf for double, %f for float
      scanf("%f", &miles);
      days++;
      }

   avg = miles / days;
   printf("average is %f\n " , avg );
   return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: Looks like you need to keep a total of all the miles - you just have a single value that you keep reading then ignoring.

Answer (score 1):

As John3136 said, you aren't keeping track of the total miles walked. You scan in miles, but you don't keep track of the sum of the miles. Your average is simply your last entered miles divided by 7.

Here is a proposed solution:

```
int main(void)
{
    // variable definition
    int days = 0;
    float avg = 0, miles = 0;

    // Loop through to input values
    while(days < 7)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of miles for each day walked: ");
        scanf("%f", &miles);
        avg += miles;
        days++;
    }

   avg /= days;
   printf("average is %.2f\n " , avg);

   return 0;
}
```

With help from Jonathan Leffler here is an enhanced version of the previous code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // variable definition
    int days = 0;
    double miles = 0.0, total_miles = 0.0;

   // Loop through to input values
    while(days < 7)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of miles for day %d: ", days + 1);

        if(!scanf("%lf", &miles))
            return -1;

        total_miles += miles;
        days++;
    }

   printf("Total miles: %.2lf / %d Days = %.2lf Average miles per day.\n",
           total_miles, days, (days > 0) ? total_miles / days : 0.0);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the value of days back to 0, but I am trying to gain the understanding of what exactly took place when //avg += miles;// and //avg /= days;//  were added. I am assuming that avg was storing the values of the days, but what specifically caused that to happen? Also, i'm not clear on why avg /= days; is not avg = avg/days. Just trying to make it all make sense.

Comment: avg += miles is shorthand for: avg = avg + miles. Also, avg /= days is the same as avg = avg / days.

We are summing up all the miles into the variables avg, then we divide this number by days.

Comment: One could argue that the variable `avg` is misnamed — or misused.  Up until the division by `days`, the value is 'total miles' rather than 'average'.  I'd likely use `double` throughout — and I'd use `double total_miles = 0.0;` and then `total_miles += miles;` and finally `double avg_miles = total_miles / days;`.   I'd also not place a trailing space after the newline in the output.  However, that's all trivia — what's here is respectable (but not perfect).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I appreciate the feedback. I actually debated with myself if I should add a total_miles variable so the output could be more clear.

Comment: YW.  One might also argue that you should check that the `scanf()` succeeds (returns `1`), and break the loop if not, perhaps protecting against division by zero too (though with floating point arithmetic, that'll evaluate to ∞ and print appropriately).  You could do without the average as a variable and simply include the expression in the `printf()` call.  It's debatable whether that's better — in context, perhaps, but in many others, the variable would be sensible.

Comment: It all makes sense now. I really appreciate the responses. I'm clearly new to stack overflow. So, can I do anything to give credit to you guys?